# Intellij Dependency Anlyzer Tool Shows conflicts that are not part of the effective pom

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a multi-module setup with the maven tool. When I use the IntelliJ Dependency Analyzer tool to review my pom.xml file it shows conflicts between dependent versions of 2 pom dependencies I have added.

Here is the image, [image]

Firstly, my effective pom does not have a dependency for the following artifact in question,

```
 <groupId>org.checkerframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>checker-qual</artifactId>
```

And secondly, Postgres has scope defined as runtime and guava has default scope.

My questions are:

1. If my effective pom does not show this dependency, why is the tool showing it under conflict?
2. If the effective pom does not show the dependency, will the packaged jar file will contain these dependencies?
3. Should I resolve this by excluding the lower version of the dependency in conflict? What happens to the scope runtime here?
4. Should I even fix this if it's not in the effective pom?

Comment: Is it possible to share sample project example for investigation?

Comment: Which version of IntelliJ are you using?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.4 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-221.6008.13, built on July 19, 2022

Comment: Could you please check the issue with the latest IDE version?

Comment: With latest IDE, my target classes are not identified and regular build breaks. So I dont want to upgrade that